# Showing list of tags used by a specific user in wordpress

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, tags

I need to show in my page template a list of tags used by a specific user. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$tags = get_tags(array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
    'post_type' => 'offer',
    'author'=> 2

));
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175950/get-tags-for-current-user?rq=1

Comment: I wanted to show for a specific user rather than the current user. Thanks for taking a look though